# UITableView Scrolling slowness issues when loading cell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, scroll

I am having issues with the speed in which my tableview Cells scroll.  You can see that it hangs up when dequeuing and reusing a cell.  Below is my code that I use to create the cells.  I am using 2 custom cells and one cell is if there is a image and the other cell is if the user didn't attach an image.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.  I should also add that I wanted to add a space between the cells so basically I create a new section containing a single cell and that is why you will always see in my code indexPath.section.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *imageCell = @"ShameImage";
        static NSString *noImageCell = @"ShameNoImageCell";
        static NSString *noCell = @"NoCell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:noCell];

        if ([[blobID objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]])
        {
            ShameViewCell *cell = (ShameViewCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:imageCell];
            if (cell == nil)
            {
                NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ShameImageCell" owner:self options:nil];
                cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
                CALayer *cellImageView = [cell.imageView layer];
                [cellImageView setMasksToBounds:YES];
                [cellImageView setCornerRadius:10.0];
                IndicatorImageView *iiv = [[IndicatorImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 88, 88)];
                [iiv setShameID:[[shameID objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] stringValue]];
                iiv.tag = 999;
                [iiv loadImageFromURL];
                [cell.imageView addSubview:iiv];
                cell.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                UITapGestureRecognizer *tapImage = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                    initWithTarget:self action:@selector(openPicture:)];
                tapImage.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
                [cell.imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapImage];

                [cell.contentView.layer setCornerRadius:10];
                [cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
                [cell.contentView setAlpha:0.7f];
                UIColor *insideColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:color_red green:color_green blue:color_blue alpha:1];

                cell.lastShame.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-11, -8, 0, 0);
                [cell.lastShame setTextColor:insideColor];
                [cell.lastShame setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:text_font_name size:14]];
                cell.lastShame.text = [userShame objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

                [cell.shameDate setTextColor:insideColor];
                [cell.shameDate setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:text_font_name size:11]];
                cell.shameDate.text = [createDt objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
                [cell.userLabel setTextColor:insideColor];
                [cell.userLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:text_font_name size:11]];
                cell.userLabel.text = [@"Post By: " stringByAppendingString:[userName objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
                [cell.lastShame setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

                return cell;
            }

        }else
        {
            ShameNoImage *cell = (ShameNoImage *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:noImageCell];
            if (cell == nil)
            {
                NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ShameNoImageCell" owner:self options:nil];
                cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
                CALayer *cellImageView = [cell.imageView layer];
                [cellImageView setMasksToBounds:YES];
                [cellImageView setCornerRadius:10.0];
                [cellImageView setBorderWidth:1.0];
                [cellImageView setBorderColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
                [cell.contentView.layer setCornerRadius:10];
                [cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
                [cell.contentView setAlpha:0.7f];
                UIColor *insideColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:color_red green:color_green blue:color_blue alpha:1];

                cell.shameLabel.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-11, -8, 0, 0);
                [cell.shameLabel setTextColor:insideColor];
                [cell.shameLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:text_font_name size:14]];
                cell.shameLabel.text = [userShame objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

                [cell.dateLabel setTextColor:insideColor];
                [cell.dateLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:text_font_name size:11]];
                cell.dateLabel.text = [createDt objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
                [cell.userLabel setTextColor:insideColor];
                [cell.userLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:text_font_name size:11]];
                cell.userLabel.text = [@"Post By: " stringByAppendingString:[userName objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
                [cell.shameLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
                return cell;
            }
        }

        return cell;
    }
```

Comment: If the `loadImageFromURL:` call hits the network synchronously, then you have one of the main reasons for your scrolling sluggishness. See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: The IndicatorImageView does load them async and puts a activity indicator in the cell during the download.  Also I should mention that it caches the image and I still have sluggish scrolling when pulling back a cached image.

Comment: Use Instruments' Time Profiler to see what's causing the biggest lag - it will let you drill down to the actual line of code that's causing lags/delays

Comment: Also, you should use opaque subviews in your cell and avoid using `clearColor`. That certainly kills scrolling performance.

Comment: The time profiler seems to point to core foundation as the time consumer.  I have gotten rid of the clearColor and rounded radius to see if it improved and it seems a little better but I still see a hang when it has to switch to do different Cell Type.

Comment: You should release some allocated views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I was recreating and drawing every cell.  I needed to set the reuseIdentifier in the Cell's Subclass and then change the building the the table to be like this.

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *imageCell = @"ShameImage";
        static NSString *noImageCell = @"ShameNoImageCell";

        ShameViewCell *iCell = (ShameViewCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:imageCell];
        ShameNoImage *niCell = (ShameNoImage *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:noImageCell];

        if ([[blobID objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] isEqualToNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]])
        {
            if (iCell == nil)
            {
                NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ShameImageCell" owner:self options:nil];
                iCell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
                CALayer *cellImageView = [iCell.imageView layer];
                [cellImageView setMasksToBounds:YES];
                IndicatorImageView *iiv = [[IndicatorImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 88, 88)];
                [iiv setShameID:[[shameID objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] stringValue]];
                iiv.tag = 999;
                [iiv loadImageFromURL];
                [iCell.imageView addSubview:iiv];
                iCell.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
                UITapGestureRecognizer *tapImage = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                    initWithTarget:self action:@selector(openPicture:)];
                tapImage.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
                [iCell.imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapImage];

                [iCell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
                [iCell.contentView setAlpha:0.7f];
                UIColor *insideColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:color_red green:color_green blue:color_blue alpha:1];

                iCell.lastShame.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-11, -8, 0, 0);
                [iCell.lastShame setTextColor:insideColor];
                [iCell.lastShame setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:text_font_name size:14]];
                iCell.lastShame.text = [userShame objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

                [iCell.shameDate setTextColor:insideColor];
                [iCell.shameDate setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:text_font_name size:11]];
                iCell.shameDate.text = [createDt objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
                [iCell.userLabel setTextColor:insideColor];
                [iCell.userLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:text_font_name size:11]];
                iCell.userLabel.text = [@"Post By: " stringByAppendingString:[userName objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];

                return iCell;
            }else
            {
                [[iCell.imageView viewWithTag:999] removeFromSuperview];
                IndicatorImageView *iiv = [[IndicatorImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 88, 88)];
                [iiv setShameID:[[shameID objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] stringValue]];
                iiv.tag = 999;
                [iiv loadImageFromURL];
                [iCell.imageView addSubview:iiv];
                iCell.lastShame.text = [userShame objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
                iCell.shameDate.text = [createDt objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
                iCell.userLabel.text = [@"Post By: " stringByAppendingString:[userName objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];

                return iCell;
            }

        }else
        {
            if (niCell == nil)
            {
                NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ShameNoImageCell" owner:self options:nil];
                niCell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
                [niCell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
                [niCell.contentView setAlpha:0.7f];
                UIColor *insideColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:color_red green:color_green blue:color_blue alpha:1];

                niCell.shameLabel.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-11, -8, 0, 0);
                [niCell.shameLabel setTextColor:insideColor];
                [niCell.shameLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:text_font_name size:14]];
                niCell.shameLabel.text = [userShame objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

                [niCell.dateLabel setTextColor:insideColor];
                [niCell.dateLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:text_font_name size:11]];
                niCell.dateLabel.text = [createDt objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
                [niCell.userLabel setTextColor:insideColor];
                [niCell.userLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:text_font_name size:11]];
                niCell.userLabel.text = [@"Post By: " stringByAppendingString:[userName objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
                return niCell;
            }else
            {
                niCell.shameLabel.text = [userShame objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
                niCell.dateLabel.text = [createDt objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
                niCell.userLabel.text = [@"Post By: " stringByAppendingString:[userName objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
                return niCell;
            }
        }
        return niCell;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that jumps out are the calls to `setCornerRadius`. A quick test would be to cut out that corner radius stuff to see if that helps your speed. If that's you're problem you'll have to switch to drawing with CG and a `UIBezierPath`.

The next thing to look at would be transparency and the number of subviews you are using. It's hard to tell with what is posted above but the more subviews, especially with alpha are going to mean more work compositing. But that can be hard to get around depending on your design but drawing with CG or using images can help.

Comment: Do you have any examples of how to use UIBezierPath?

Comment: Here is one example of [Sam Soffes Cheddar app](https://github.com/nothingmagical/cheddar-ios/blob/master/Classes/CDIGroupedTableViewCell.m). Was that the source of your problem?